Is it possible to instantiate a project via a jar file so that the body of library methods does not equal None?
My static analysis is detecting java.lang.reflection calls which is working.
For additional unsoundness detection I want to inspect wether the parameters of these calls are constants, intraprocedural (instanciated inside the callers body) or interprocedural(instantiated outside the callers body).
To get to that i am trying to compute the TACode for the detected reflection methods to get information about their parameters.
Computing the project. The variable File is holding the jar that is getting analyzed:
val project: Project[URL] = Project(file, org.opalj.bytecode.RTJar)
Computing TACode:
...
type V = DUVar[ValueInformation]
    implicit val tacai : Method => TACode[TACMethodParameter,V] = rootService.projectInfo.project.get(LazyTACUsingAIKey)

    
    val temp = tacai.apply(pReflectMethod.method)
...

This throws a noSuchElementException.
The body attribute of those library methods equal None. That is probably the root of the problem.
Is there any solution to initialize reachable methods of librarys with their corresponding bodys?
I have already tried to change org.opalj.bytecode.RTJar inside the project creation to org.opalj.bytecode.JRELibraryFolder. That did not work.
I have also tried to fetch the method via the declaredMethod which also did not work nor changed the fact, that the body = None
